# Is there any Python package which allows parsing .po files (messages, including context comments)?

Tags: python, internationalization, translation, globalization

I need to merge/update/delete .po files messages and need some Python package which allow me to parse fully .po files including: messages, plurals, location, context and comments.

I want do simple tool which will check differences between to files. I could use also some GUI is already done but not sure if there such tool which will add new translation or remove not used translation.

I was search some articles but not found how to do it. Please recommend some Python package which parse .po fully (could other language) or tool to do such important task to keep good translations.

Answer (score 5):

The [polib](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/polib) package is very good. It parses the file and presents several ways to access the data, including an iterator to loop through the msgid, msgstr pairs to do whatever you need. Here is the [Quick Start documentation](http://polib.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart.html).

It can also parse a .mo if the .po isn't available, specially handle obsolete message strings, iterate over only translated strings, and other nice features.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need fancy tools to read `.po` files; they are plain text files which basically contain message/translation pairs:

```
#: buttons.c:425
msgid "Extra"
msgstr "Thêm"

#: buttons.c:433
msgid "Help"
msgstr "Trợ giúp"
```

For a simple tool to compare them, I would suggest using `diff -u`.

There is a binary format with the `.mo` extension. You can use the `msgunfmt` program from the gettext-tools package to convert them back into plain text.

Extracting id/translation pairs from `.po` files is not difficult:

```
In [1]: po = '''#: buttons.c:425
   ...: msgid "Extra"
   ...: msgstr "Thêm"
   ...: 
   ...: #: buttons.c:433
   ...: msgid "Help"
   ...: msgstr "Trợ giúp"
   ...: 
   ...: '''

In [2]: import re

In [3]: re.findall('^msgid \"(.*)\"', po, re.MULTILINE)
Out[3]: ['Extra', 'Help']

In [4]: re.findall('^msgstr \"(.*)\"', po, re.MULTILINE)
Out[4]: ['Th\xc3\xaam', 'Tr\xe1\xbb\xa3 gi\xc3\xbap']

In [5]: zip(re.findall('^msgid \"(.*)\"[^\"]*', po, re.MULTILINE), re.findall('^msgstr \"(.*)\"[^\"]*', po, re.MULTILINE))
Out[5]: [('Extra', 'Th\xc3\xaam'), ('Help', 'Tr\xe1\xbb\xa3 gi\xc3\xbap')]
```

I'm using the `^` and `re.MULTILINE` to prevent commented-out messages to turn up here. As a sanity check, make sure that the list containing the message-ids and the message strings are of equal length.

**Edit:** You have a valid point regarding the random orderering and using `diff`. But you could use the code above to make lists of (message-id, translation) tuples for both the old and new `.po` file. If you sort those lists by the message-id you could use [`difflib.unified_diff`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html#difflib.unified_diff) to print the differences.

For example:

```
In [1]: import re, itertools, difflib

#I've used cpaste to input two pieces of a .po file, the latter with some changes

In [4]: orig_po
Out[4]: '#: mixedgauge.c:64\nmsgid "Passed"\nmsgstr "\xc4\x90\xe1\xbb\x97"\n\n#: mixedgauge.c:67\nmsgid "Completed"\nmsgstr "Ho\xc3\xa0n to\xc3\xa0n"\n\n#: mixedgauge.c:70\nmsgid "Checked"\nmsgstr "\xc4\x90\xc3\xa3 ki\xe1\xbb\x83m tra"\n\n#: mixedgauge.c:73\nmsgid "Done"\nmsgstr "Ho\xc3\xa0n t\xe1\xba\xa5t"\n\n#: mixedgauge.c:76\nmsgid "Skipped"\nmsgstr "B\xe1\xbb\x8b b\xe1\xbb\x8f qua"\n\n#: mixedgauge.c:79\nmsgid "In Progress"\nmsgstr "\xc4\x90ang ch\xe1\xba\xa1y"\n\n#: mixedgauge.c:85\nmsgid "N/A"\nmsgstr "Kh\xc3\xb4ng c\xc3\xb3"\n\n#: mixedgauge.c:193\nmsgid "Overall Progress"\nmsgstr "To\xc3\xa0n ti\xe1\xba\xbfn h\xc3\xa0nh"\n'

In [5]: changed_po
Out[5]: '#: mixedgauge.c:64\nmsgid "Passed"\nmsgstr "\xc4\x90\xe1\xbb\x97"\n\n#: mixedgauge.c:193\nmsgid "Overall Progres"\nmsgstr "To\xc3\xa0n ti\xe1\xba\xbfn h\xc3\xa0nh"\n\n#: mixedgauge.c:67\nmsgid "Completed"\nmsgstr "Ho\xc3\xa0na to\xc3\xa0n"\n\n#: mixedgauge.c:76\nmsgid "Skipped"\nmsgstr "B\xe1\xbb\x8b b\xe1\xbb\x8f qua"\n\n#: mixedgauge.c:79\nmsgid "In Progress"\nmsgstr "\xc4\x90ang ch\xe1\xba\xa1y"\n\n#: mixedgauge.c:85\nmsgid "N/A"\nmsgstr "Kh\xc3\xb4ng c\xc3\xb3e"\n\n#: mixedgauge.c:70\nmsgid "Checked"\nmsgstr "\xc4\x90\xc3\xa3 ki\xe1\xbb\x83m tra"\n\n#: mixedgauge.c:73\nmsgid "Done"\nmsgstr "Ho\xc3\xa0n t\xe1\xba\xa5t"\n'

# Making a list of tuples

In [6]: orig_list = zip(re.findall('^(msgid \".*\")', orig_po, re.MULTILINE), re.findall('^(msgstr \".*\")', orig_po, re.MULTILINE))

In [7]: changed_list = zip(re.findall('^(msgid \".*\")', changed_po, re.MULTILINE), re.findall('^(msgstr \".*\")', changed_po, re.MULTILINE))

# Sort them by the message-id

In [8]: orig_list.sort(key=lambda t: t[0])

In [9]: changed_list.sort(key=lambda t: t[0])

# Now flatten the list

In [10]: orig_string_list = [i for i in itertools.chain(*orig_list)]

In [11]: changed_string_list = [i for i in itertools.chain(*changed_list)]

In [12]: orig_list[0:3]
Out[12]: [('msgid "Checked"', 'msgstr "\xc4\x90\xc3\xa3 ki\xe1\xbb\x83m tra"'), ('msgid "Completed"', 'msgstr "Ho\xc3\xa0n to\xc3\xa0n"'), ('msgid "Done"', 'msgstr "Ho\xc3\xa0n t\xe1\xba\xa5t"')]

In [13]: orig_string_list[0:6]
Out[13]: ['msgid "Checked"', 'msgstr "\xc4\x90\xc3\xa3 ki\xe1\xbb\x83m tra"', 'msgid "Completed"', 'msgstr "Ho\xc3\xa0n to\xc3\xa0n"', 'msgid "Done"', 'msgstr "Ho\xc3\xa0n t\xe1\xba\xa5t"']

# print the diff

In [14]: for l in difflib.unified_diff(orig_string_list, changed_string_list, fromfile='original', tofile='changed'):
   ....:     print l
   ....:     
--- original

+++ changed

@@ -1,14 +1,14 @@

 msgid "Checked"
 msgstr "Đã kiểm tra"
 msgid "Completed"
-msgstr "Hoàn toàn"
+msgstr "Hoàna toàn"
 msgid "Done"
 msgstr "Hoàn tất"
 msgid "In Progress"
 msgstr "Đang chạy"
 msgid "N/A"
-msgstr "Không có"
-msgid "Overall Progress"
+msgstr "Không cóe"
+msgid "Overall Progres"
 msgstr "Toàn tiến hành"
 msgid "Passed"
 msgstr "Đỗ"
```

Comment: Thanks for advice - I want to avoid writing another parser but as you said it is very easy to write parser. Whatever still think that there is some more high level solution. Diff -u is not valid for compare since order of string could be random - if .po file will be fully parser it is possible to sort it and try winmerge but it is still low level - I want to simplify it to right, left, delete, add. Translators could make mistakes and generate high cost of tests and debug better not allow them mistakes including me :)

Comment: @Chameleon I've added an example how to make a _sorted_ unified diff in python.

Comment: Thanks - I currenty testing PoEdit + Google Translation Toolkit. It is not perfect but looks that could be used. Here is very nice automation see translator toolkit (at bottom) - http://translate.google.com/.

I will study your code soon.

Comment: These code examples only work in ideal cases. Once you have multiline messages or plural forms, the regexes just fall into pieces. Not to mention inefficiency for larger files.

Answer (score 2):

Try the [babel](http://babel.edgewall.org/) module. it includes a `.po` parser in `babel.messages.catalog` and `babel.messages.pofile` among other things.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try soon. I am writing some open source Python i18n eclipse plugin maybe will include merging po files.